# How does ISP intercept web traffic?

Tags: http

My question originates from following articles:

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/07/14/cloudflare_investigating_mystery_interception_of_site_traffic_across_india/

and

https://medium.com/@karthikb351/airtel-is-sniffing-and-censoring-cloudflares-traffic-in-india-and-they-don-t-even-know-it-90935f7f6d98#.zduskeffu

I wanted to understand how does ISP intercept web traffic? Do they block DNS request? However, this can be circumvented with using different DNS servers. OR Do they block http get requests? I have no knowledge of traffic interception, however; I feel this is the most plausible method.

My reason for stating the above is because whenever I try to visit a website blocked (or redirected to a block page) by my ISP it is usually a http request. If I add https in the URL the website appears and I have access to it.

For example: http://websitename.com – blocked https://websitename.com – full access.

Thanks!

Comment: So CouldFlare is investigating, but you think you'll get the answer from StackExchange community? Just curious...

Comment: Dear Techarf, I am asking this question to information technology community at large. For example, a proxy is a way ISP's intercept traffic. However, I wanted to understand beyond what my knowledge base is.

Comment: And you are convinced such "for example" question is different from *an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”* as listed on [what questions not to ask](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) list?

Comment: Parth, since you use this ISP, all you need is Wireshark and [tutorials](http://www.securitytube.net/video/11) to answer this question in this specific case. A general overview of technical blocking by ISPs can be found [here](https://opennet.net/about-filtering) and [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2405036).

Comment: Dear Techarf, my example is not open ended. It is specific to use of HTTP VS HTTPS in URL. Pardon me if I've violated any T&C of the website.

Comment: There are multiple ways this can be done given that they control the network.  Even secured connections could get similarly intercepted and blocked but that might not be what they want since it wouldn't be possible to know the actual target live because of the encryption.  CloudFlare has the system, resources and money to investigate it and you're trying to ask people to tell you what is their problem.  This doesn't make any sense.  If you want to learn, go ahead and read on the subject but no one here will spend any time trying to find why poor CloudFlare is getting blocked.

Comment: Thank you Julie, please note that my question vendor or service provider neutral. I am not asking how it was done in this one particular case. Answer by @Jedi seem to suffice my query. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Also see chapter 3 [here](https://opennet.net/node/206) for tools and other chapters for more coverage. It's slightly dated but has nice figures.

Comment: "Cloudflare investigating mystery interception" ... while that, I caught them pants down routing IP addresses that did not had hosting, services or other any type of contact with them. Sorry for the off-topic, but my trust in them accidentally defaulted to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISP can intercept traffic in any number of ways, from a proxy (like you suggest, though I would suspect a transparent proxy), to a span port on a switch. If they have control over a link in the chain between you and the Internet, they can see anything that passes through it. If it's encrypted data, the ISP can use an SSL inspector ([like this](https://www.untangle.com/shop/ssl-inspector/)), but that would be pretty obvious to you.

In reference to filtering, if your ISP is filtering based on the content of the website you're viewing (keywords, for example), or the destination (host, http resource), then making that request over SSL will inhibit their ability to see what you're requesting and from whom. They can still see your initial DNS request and the IP address that your request is sent to on the network layer however.